# redirect LDAP with TLS with SSH

Tags: ldap, ssh-tunnel

I need to query an LDAP server with TLS enabled. The LDAP server is behind a firewall. 
It only accepts queries with TLS enabled (`-Z` option).

I redirected the LDAP port like this:

```
oz123@devhost ~ $ ssh -l oz123 -L8888:ldapserver:389 buildhost
```

Now when I try to query the host, I get an error:

```
    oz123@devhost ~ $ ldapsearch  -Z -h localhost -p 8888 -D uid=oz123,ou=people,dc=company,dc=de '(cn=*time*)' -W
ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
    additional info: (unknown error code)
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

I verified that the tunnel works with telnet, and the LDAP server respond to anonymous queries.

**Can someone give me a hint how and which ports need to be redirected so that I can start TLS connections?**

#### update:

`-d 1` shows:

```
TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x42)
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
```

Comment: It might be certificate mismatch with certificate name ldapserver!=localhost or a missing CA Certificate? try `LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never ldapsearch ...` or adding debug options to your commandline eg `ldapsearch -d -1 ...`

Comment: @HBruijn, Setting the LDAPTLS_REQCERT variable helps avoiding the `Connect error`, but now I am not getting any search results from this ldap...

Comment: Try adding the `-W` cmdline option before the ldap filter/search string, rather then add the end of your commandline.

Comment: @HBruijn, does not make a change. I think this LDAP is configured not to respond to all hosts